# Running VS In IIS Mode and pressing F5

Tags: asp.net

I prefer running VS over IIS (not cassini).  I've always though manually attached to the worker process via file menu.  Can you just use F5 just as you can with Cassini only it's doing the same wiring tot he asp.net worker process but working with IIS not cassini?  It looks like it, I never really tried F5 for a while after moving to use IIS like 7 years ago but looks like you can still just press F5 evenif you're using IIS mode (virtual directoryin IIS, setting your VS web project to use IIS virtual directory).

concur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, you can do that.

Create the site on IIS first.

1. Then in VS right-click on your site root under Solution Explorer.
2. on the new window, select 'Start Options'
3. in here, you can select 'Use Custom Server' and provide the Base URL to your site, maybe something like `http://localhost` (whatever you set your bindings to)

It should now run through IIS when you press F5

Is this what you meant? Sorry if i misunderstood..

Comment: yea that's what I mean I know how to set it up - that's not my question as to how...I just didn't know you could still use F5 in that case.  I guess though I still prefer attaching manually as I don't have to close my browser tab each time and relaunch a new one.  To me that's annoying more than attaching it manually.

Comment: Yep, i know what you mean, though if it's a web site rather than application then you don't need to close your browser; unless its something like the Masterpage.